# How to separate the UI Appearance Customization from View Controller?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

In HTML + CSS, If I want to create three buttons with the same appearance, I can add a class to a div, and define the appearance in CSS. So that when I want to update the appearance again, I can only update CSS.

In iOS, I usually init and define appearance of UI Control in View Controller. How to separate the UI Appearance Customization from View Controller? Are there any best practice, design pattern, or framework about it?

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing all my UIAppearance customization in the `initialize` method of the app delegate. You can use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` method to do the equivalent of a div and CSS.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], 
     [UIPopoverController class], nil] setTintColor:myPopoverNavBarColor];
```

Comment: Thanks! But looks not as simple as CSS. I think it might be better to allow me write css, then a library can read each css rule, convert them into the UIAppearance customization.